# Cannot import declaration file

Tags: typescript, chai, chai-http

I'm trying to set up some test for my RESTAPI server. I use typescript.
I tried to import `chai` and `chai-http` using the ES6 syntax, but apparently, it's not supported ([Github issue here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/19480) ). I get an error, so I had to `require` the files directly.

```
var chai = require('chai')
    , chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

import *  from '@types/chai-http';

/* 
 * Both librairies have limited support of ES6 import.
 * See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/19480
*/

chai.use(chaiHttp);

import { expect } from 'chai' ;
import 'mocha';
```

Now the thing is typescript doesn't import `@types/chai-http` for some reason, so when I try to use `expect(res).to.have.status(201);`, I get an error, the compiler complain

```
Error TS2339: Property status does not exist on type Assertion
```

How do I import the type declaration directly?

Thanks